# How to add active class if current url matches the given (twig)

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

I want to write manually a side menu for the store on opencart, and I have a problem - how to make twig add the class "active" to the link for current page

I tried to do it like this

```
<a href="/something/" class="list-group-item {{ (app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'something') ? 'active' }}">page about something</a>
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: Did you test out what `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` returns?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the category module does so you can copy it:

```
{% if child.category_id == child_id %}
    <a href="{{ child.href }}" class="list-group-item active">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- {{ child.name }}</a> 
{% else %} 
    <a href="{{ child.href }}" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- {{ child.name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

You can find the file above here:

```
/catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/category.twig
```

You can find its controller here:

```
/catalog/controller/extension/module/category.php
```

Comment: it is not for category or product pages, I want left side menu for information pages, but including only chosen pages, not all

Comment: I know. My code example above is for the *category module* not the *category page*. The module can be placed on any page as described here: https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/how-do-opencart-layouts-work/

Answer (score -1):

They way I would do it is out the route request in by the controller phone file. This would be something like the below:

```
$urlroute = $this->request->get['route'];
```

Then in the twig file you could simply check the route variable in an IF query

```
{% if urlroute ==  "something" % }
    <a href="/something/" class="list-group-item active">page about something</a>
{% else %} 
    <a href="/something/" class="list-group-item">page about something</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is the exact same code `OP` is using but stretched out. Don't see how this would solve the problem

Comment: This is using the code to match how opencart is coded. Do you even know anything about opencart?